# slight url mismatch while publishing java 6 maven webapp to tomcat from netbeans

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, maven-2, netbeans, maven-cargo

Honestly I've started this small maven webapp using eclipse 3.6 (STS) and i found it so complicated that i had to switch to netbeans.I really wanted to use eclipse but these are reality on the ground.So at the end of everything I'll like to have an eclipse version of the same project. thanks

I set up the maven webapp using the embedded archetype, and use cargo plugin to take care of the deployment.basically there is only `hello world index.jsp` in the project.after picking pom configuration here and there my pom finally is like  [this](http://pastie.org/1649273) . 
while it started publishing after i restart the IDE, it's publishing to http://localhost:8080/ but for me I'm expecting it at http://localhost:8080/mvnTestWebap

so here are my questions

- **Question 1** :  How can i correct that?
- **Question 2** : I believe my pom is tied to netbeans too much, how can i achieve the publishing to tomcat result but having a portable pom?Can anyone suggest a rewrite that can run on eclipse?
- **Question 3** : what correspond to netbeans "run" in eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

1. probably by some deployment descriptor editing.
2. don't really understand the point. by default netbeans uses it's own embedded IDE way of deployment. That's not creating a pom tied to netbeans in any way. You can use that in eclipse or IDE or command line to build the project. The deployment part of the web app is specific to the server being used and the IDE being used.
   You can also tell netbeans to execute your cargo plugin on executing the Run/Debug/Profile action (bypassing the netbeans default behaviour)
3. run basically performs a redeploy of the app on the server of choice. There has to be an equivalent on eclipse.

Comment: thanks for the answer.Can you elaborate a bit on the question 1 please